# unsafeRead causing stack overflow

Tags: haskell, stack-overflow

Here's some code that does bounds checks at [ideone](http://ideone.com/QiwTJ).

It runs successfully with no out of bounds error.

In [this](http://ideone.com/iOO1c) code, on line 34 I have changed on `readArray` to `unsafeRead`, and it still compiles, but crashes with a stack overflow.

Is this a GHC bug or have I done something wrong?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`unsafeRead` uses 0-based indices, so you have to either adjust the index for reading,

```
elem <- unsafeRead arr (i-1)
```

or, better, allocate the array with a least index of 0

```
arr <- newArray (0,upperbound) maxBound
```

As is, the `unsafeRead` reads from the wrong place in the array.

Unrelated: I suspect ideone uses a 32-bit GHC, so better don't run the code with `upperbound > 100000` there.

Comment: Also note that `unsafeRead` takes an Int, while `readArray` takes an `Ix`, which should be a tip off to something going on...